# Anchor links not working on iPad but working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I am working on a website with anchor links that scroll to the specific section. Everything works fine on desktop, the I added the following script to make it work on mobile.

```
<script> 
 $(function() {
        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
           if (screen.width <= 1400) {
          if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
              }, 1000);
              return false;
            }
          }
           }
        });
      }); 

</script>
```

The script works perfectly on phones (tested on iPhone) but doesn't work on iPad. The anchor links instead of scrolling just jump to their section.

https://pacific-demo.squarespace.com

I am using this template which on its original form has the same problem but still I don't get why while the script above works on phones, it ignores the iPads....

Comment: Have you tried seeing if it works with touch events like `touchstart`?